ORM Sequelize model.upsert() is not a function
Version sequelize 6.37.3
I try to upsert() myModel but the mehtod returns:

TypeError: model.upsert is not a function

my_model.controller.ts
...
class MyModelController {
    private model: any;
    ...
    async put(req: Request, res: Response) {
        // get stored model 
        const model = await this.model.findByPk(currentId, {
            attributes: ['id'],
            include: {
                model: MyModelStatus,
                attributes: ['name']
            }
        });
        // set model attributes
        ...
        // validate model
        ...
        // execute query
        const [instance, created] = await model.upsert({}); // ERROR ===> model.upsert is not a function
        console.log(instance, created) 
    }

myModel holds base data and objects like status, address etc.
Below shown the model myModel instance:
MyModel {
  dataValues: {
    id: '68ab6267-e6fa-49b9-a3b4-d9c4bfd4b785',
    MyModelStatus: MyModelStatus {
      dataValues: [Object],
      _previousDataValues: [Object],
      uniqno: 1,
      _changed: Set(0) {},
      _options: [Object],
      isNewRecord: false
    },
    firstName: 'User',
    lastName: 'User',
    email: 'abc@def.com',
    phone: '12345678',
    editorID: '8b8dfcfd-9c37-450e-a733-81d85421f285',
    genderOfficial: 'male',
    birthDate: '2024-07-25',
    myModelStatusID: 'f2725742-0320-4249-8b57-9523a6003363'
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    id: '68ab6267-e6fa-49b9-a3b4-d9c4bfd4b785',
    MyModelStatus: MyModelStatus {
      dataValues: [Object],
      _previousDataValues: [Object],
      uniqno: 1,
      _changed: Set(0) {},
      _options: [Object],
      isNewRecord: false
    },
    firstName: undefined,
    lastName: undefined,
    email: undefined,
    phone: undefined,
    editorID: undefined,
    genderOfficial: undefined,
    birthDate: undefined,
    myModelStatusID: undefined
  },
  uniqno: 1,
  _changed: Set(8) {
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
    'email',
    'phone',
    'editorID',
    'genderOfficial',
    'birthDate',
    'myModelStatusID'
  },
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    include: [ [Object] ],
    includeNames: [ 'MyModelStatus' ],
    includeMap: { MyModelStatus: [Object] },
    includeValidated: true,
    attributes: [ 'id' ],
    raw: true
  },
  isNewRecord: false,
  status: MyModelStatus {
    dataValues: { name: 'new' },
    _previousDataValues: { name: 'new' },
    uniqno: 1,
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      include: undefined,
      includeNames: undefined,
      includeMap: undefined,
      includeValidated: true,
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  },
  address: MyModelAddress {
    dataValues: {
      id: '5564d4b7-09c0-4633-b2c3-8b06376fad67',
      streetNumber: '123',
      street: 'bla',
      postalCode: '123456',
      city: 'anywhwere',
      country: 'anywhere',
      myModelID: '68ab6267-e6fa-49b9-a3b4-d9c4bfd4b785',
      createdAt: 2024-07-15T10:10:30.533Z,
      updatedAt: 2024-07-15T10:10:30.533Z
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      streetNumber: undefined,
      street: undefined,
      postalCode: undefined,
      city: undefined,
      country: undefined,
      myModelID: undefined,
      createdAt: undefined,
      updatedAt: undefined
    },
    uniqno: 1,
    _changed: Set(8) {
      'streetNumber',
      'street',
      'postalCode',
      'city',
      'country',
      'myModelID',
      'createdAt',
      'updatedAt'
    },
    _options: { isNewRecord: true, _schema: null, _schemaDelimiter: '' },
    isNewRecord: true
  }
}

Questions:

Why is upsert() not a function?
How to make the request work?


Which version of sequelize do you use?

"sequelize": "6.37.3",

You simply mixed up this.model and model. upsert is the static and not an instance method:
const [instance, created] = await this.model.upsert({});

